# Iterate through list using scheduleAtFixedRate in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, iterator, runnable

I'm trying to iterate through a list based on a timer which the user can set. However I can't find a good way to do it within the `TimerTask` runnable.

The general idea can be found in the code I've shared below. `Announcements` is a `List` of `List<String>`. On every interval I want to take the next `announcement` from `announcements` and display the strings within it. I've got all of it working except the timer going over multiple `announcements`:

```
 timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        int iterator = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {

            List<String> announcement = announcements.get(iterator);

            for (String line : announcement) {
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(line);
            }

            iterator++;
            if(iterator > announcements.size()){
                iterator = 0;
            }
        }
    }, 0, (int)config.get("interval")*1000);
```

Using the code I posted I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and it never even posts any of the messages. If I remove the iterator code it will show the first `announcement` endlessly.

Comment: Can you describe what exactly is going wrong with your current implementation? What is the desired behaviour and how does the current behaviour differ from that? What do you mean by "...except the timer going over multiple announcements"?

Comment: Sorry if my question was a bit unclear, It's my first time posting and I didn't really know how to word the questions. Luckily some other guy helped my out through the code example. Thanks for commenting tho :)

Comment: One thing to note here is that Timer doesn't handle exceptions very well. Try 'ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor' for better handling of exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong following condition:

```
if(iterator > announcements.size())
```

In this case the size of the list is exceeded so [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is thrown. But the condition should check is the `iterator` greater or **equal** to size of list:

```
if(iterator >= announcements.size())
```